# Find the latest location of each users in a MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table where I want to find the latest location of each user using an SQL query.

The table contains the columns, (1)email, (2)timestamp, (3)location.

So if the table looks like this:

```
email            timestamp    location
user1@email.com  27.08.2014   kitchen
user1@email.com  28.08.2014   livingroom
user1@email.com  29.08.2014   kitchen
user2@email.com  26.08.2014   hallway
user2@email.com  27.08.2014   kitchen
```

I want it to output:

```
email            timestamp    location
user1@email.com  29.08.2014   kitchen
user2@email.com  27.08.2014   kitchen
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT yt.* FROM your_table yt
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
    email, MAX(timestamp) max_ts
    FROM
    your_table 
    GROUP BY email
) sq ON yt.email = sq.email AND yt.timestamp = sq.max_ts
```

- find more examples of how to do it here: [The Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//example-maximum-column-group-row.html)